# How to find the determinant for each square matrix in an array?

Tags: r

I have an array of 747 square matrices. Let us say this array is called m.
Using det(m[,,1]) gives me the determinant of the first square matrix. Likewise det(m[,,2]) gives me the determinant of the second square matrix and so on and so forth. Is there a function that calculates the determinant for each square matrix in the array? I tried using a for loop but it did not work.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a sample of your data, but here is a simple example. In your case `det.all` will be a list of 747 determinants:

```
m <- array(1:16, c(2, 2, 4))
det.all <- lapply(seq(dim(m)[3]), function(x) det(m[,,x]))
det.all
# [[1]]
# [1] -2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] -2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] -2
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] -2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` over the 3rd dimension as shown:

```
a <- array((1:12)^2, c(2, 2, 3)) # test data

apply(a, 3, det)
[1]  -20 -164 -436

# verify that the above values are correct

det(a[,,1])
## [1] -20

det(a[,,2])
## [1] -164

det(a[,,3])
## [1] -436
```

Comment: I tried that before but got the error message: "Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed."

Comment: You can see from the reproducible example given in the answer that it works. 
You will need to provide a reproducible example that allows anyone else to generate that error and in general follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page when posting.